# Joomla 3.0—standalone application for test purposes

Tags: unit-testing, testing, joomla, integration-testing

I just came over the topic about running Joomla as standalone application ([a wiki entry here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Platform)) and the first thing that came into my mind was: »That might be quiet practical for building test cases!«, so does anybody know about some kind of resources, covering that topic? Are there any tutorials, or is it not possible or stupid to try to use a standalone Joomla application to build tests for a website?

Comment: What kind of test cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can build from the Joomla Platform (the code found at `libraries/joomla` and `libraries/legacy` in the CMS distro) for simple things.  But, I've found it difficult to build anything more than simple applications with the Platform without having to resort to CMS like code structures and techniques.  I've got one of those simple cases [on GitHub](https://github.com/mbabker/J30UpgradeCheck) which also incorporates the CMS library.

As for automated testing, browse the [Platform repository's tests folder](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/tree/staging/tests).  There's a fairly decent unit test structure in place there with mocks for many of the higher level classes.

So, it's possible, if you're willing to do some legwork.